# How to use Linux without any user and permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to use Linux without any user. I mean I want to use Linux system in way I run processes without any user, and freely edit any folder and any file without any permission entity. Yes, I additionally want that my system being totally unsecured. Maybe I need to use other OS or how I can do it?

Comment: By definition any process runs as a user. The closest you can get is running anything as root, that is just stupid, and I further believe some programs will refuse to do anything as root.

Comment: Without any user, it's impossible, the closest is to use root. You can also try to install into a FAT32 filesystem: no user or any permission. Basicly what you want looks like MS-DOS / Windows 3.x!

Comment: An written by cylgalad, every process (and file) has a user associated with it (per design. process 1 is set as root, other processes inherit parent user by default). This is not only a security feature, but also a tracking and management utility. I can kill all processes started by the webserver by specify the webserver user, I can check what process is writting logs, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically: this is a difficult question to answer completely, and it starts with: `what is your definition of Linux` (e.g. "Ubuntu vs. the Linux kernel" is an apples vs. oranges type of question) and quickly expands into a scoping discussion about what sorts of applications you need and, if you need to use existing programs, how you plan to modify them.

Practically: set your uid to 0 (in the `/etc/passwd` file) and you'll be the `root` user who can create, edit or remove any file.

Comment: Note: some programs don't allow to be run as root, or with unnecessary permissions.

Comment: Thanks you, i understand now that this is impossible. And the closest is to use root.

Answer (score 2):

Boot in *Single User Mode*

If your goal is to eliminate user/owner permissions, you might want to look into **Kali Linux**.
It was designed for *ultimate penetration tests*, utilizes one SuperUser.